# Web App with Spring - Using properties in Service

Tags: java, spring

I want to load few values from a proporties files that is in the /WEB-INF/ folder.
I usually use this in my xml file when I develop a software using WebServices

```
<util:properties id="configProperties" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/config.properties" />
```

and then access to the value in Java using:

```
@Value("#{configProperties['clientURL']}")
private String clientURL;

public String urlClient() {
    return clientURL;
}
```

But it doesn't work on my webapp, it's always returning the `null` value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here:
http://codingbone.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-load-properties-files-into-spring-and-expose-to-the-java-classes/

Answer (score 3):

`WEB-INF` is not on the classpath. The classpath starts from `WEB-INF/classes/`. So I would advise to place the properties file there (and change the `location` property accordingly). The service layer should not know that it serves a web application (which has `WEB-INF`)

Comment: Except that it returns a "FileNotFoundException" when the properties file is somewhere else.

Comment: what do you put in "location" ?

Comment: In the xml file:
`<util:properties id="configProperties" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/configModule.properties" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="regiesService" address="/RegiesService" implementor="ch.usefulweb.regies.service.remote.RegiesServiceImpl" />`

Comment: well, if you move the file but don't change the location, it won't work. Change the location to `classpath:/configModule.properties`

Comment: Same exception, FileNotFound, but I don't understand why would I need to change the file location if the webapp clearly see it, it would raise an exception otherwise.

Comment: The webapp does, but it is not on the classpat, and thw service layer does not know about the web context

Comment: About the class path it was my mistake, I took the project from someone else and he put a WEB-INF inside WEB-INF/classes/